# iOS UIWebView set language for html page

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, localization

I'm building a website that will be used as app by UIWebView. My website locale is italian, my app locale is italian, but input type controls in html has english text (as in attach).
How i can fix it?

[image: Input file]

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I ever met the same problem and fixed that as below, in XCode 7:

In info.plist, Add "Localizations" if it doesn't exist, expand to its child items, and set one of them to your desired language to declare that your app serves this kind of language.

And the actual display language is also impacted by language setting of your device, make sure that Settings->General->Language & Region->Language in your device is set to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For X-Code 13: under Project Navigation select your App and click on the Info tab and under Localizations add your language of choice.